# How to manipulate rasters after stacking them?

Tags: r, raster

I have some rasters that I want to compute the moving average and then rewrite the rasters again.

```
  r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- r4 <- r5 <- r6 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10);
  r1 <- setValues(r1,runif(100,min=1,max=100));
  r2 <- setValues(r2,runif(100,min=1,max=100));
  r3 <- setValues(r3,runif(100,min=1,max=100));
  r4 <- setValues(r4,runif(100,min=1,max=100));
  r5 <- setValues(r5,runif(100,min=1,max=100));
  r6 <- setValues(r6,runif(100,min=1,max=100));
  # Stack them
  st1 <- stack(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6)
  #compute the moving average:
  x <- calc(st1, function(x) movingFun(x, 3, mean))
```

Now the layers in `x` should be recalculated as:

```
  firstlayer=(first layer + fourth layer)/2
  secondlayer=(second layer + fifth layer)/2
  thirdlayer=(third layer + sixth layer)/2
```

These are examples but my data are more than this so I prefer a loop to do the job no matter how many layers I have in `x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
  library(raster)
  # creating the same data set, but in fewer lines
  r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
  s <- stack(lapply(1:6, function(...) setValues(r, runif(100,min=1,max=100))))
  x <- calc(st1, function(x) movingFun(x, 3, mean))

  # remove the edges to line up the layers that need to be added
  nl <- nlayers(x)
  x1 <- x[[-c((nl-2):nl)]]  
  x2 <- x[[-c(1:3)]]

  z <- x1 + x2 / 2
```

See ?stackApply for some other cases

Comment: More discussion here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142679/how-to-compute-layer-by-layer-after-stack